# Using _extend in a grandchild theme

Tags: magento2, theme, parent-child-theme, component

I have a question regarding how Magento 2 Less handles _extend.

According to the documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html I can extend a specific component vs overwriting it.

I have a child theme that I'm using `Magento/Blank` as a parent. I also have a second theme that uses my child theme and I use that for specific category styling.

If I follow the instructions in the documentation and create a file

```
web/css/source/_navigation_extend.less
```

and add `_navigation_extend.less`

to `_extend.less`, it shows up properly on my child theme. The problem is those same styles aren't applied to my grandchild theme.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The (grand)child-theme inherits `_extend.less` (and therefore `_navigation_extend.less`) from its parent-theme, unless it is overridden in your child theme.

So please make sure your child-theme does not contains one (or both) of these files:

```
web/css/source/_extend.less
web/css/source/_navigation_extend.less
```

Because if it does then it is overriding your styling from the parent-theme and it would explain why the styles aren't applied.